# Beautiful Soup saving sessions to checkout products

Tags: python-3.x, session, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to write a bot to add items to my cart then purchase them for me because I need to make very regular purchases and it becomes tedious to purchase them myself.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import numpy as np


page = requests.get("http://www.onlinestore.com/shop")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
try:
    for i in soup.find_all('a'):

        if "shop" in i['href']:
            shop_page = requests.get("http://www.onlinestore.com" + i['href'])
            item_page = BeautifulSoup(shop_page.content, 'html.parser')
            for h in item_page.find_all('form', class_="add"):
                print(h['action'])
                try:
                    shop_page = requests.get("http://www.online.com" + h['action'])
                except:
                    print("None left")
            for h in item_page.find_all('h1', class_="protect"):
                print(h.getText())
except:
    print("either ended or error occured")
checkout_page = requests.get("http://www.onlinestore.com/checkout")

checkout = BeautifulSoup(checkout_page.content, 'html.parser')
for j in checkout.find_all('strong', id_="total"):
    print(j)
```

I was having some trouble checking out the products because the items don't carry over. Is there a way that I can implement cookies so that it keeps track my items I have added to cart?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even though `requests` is not a browser, it still can persist headers and cookies across multiple requests, but if you use a [`Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects):

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    page = session.get("http://www.onlinestore.com/shop")

    # use "session" instead of "requests" later on
```

Note that you would also get a performance boost for free because of the *persistent connection*:

> if you're making several requests to the same host, *the underlying TCP
>   connection will be reused, which can result in a significant*
>   performance increase

Depending on how the cart and checkout on this specific online store are implemented this may or may not work. But, at least, this is a step forward.